# Arm endurance specific training

Tags: endurance, arms, muscle-endurance

I need suggestions for developing muscle endurance on my delts, triceps, biceps and forearm flexors.

Reasons: personal goals.

Expectations: being able to do noticeably way more work with arms than am I able to do now.

Any idea on how to achieve my goal fast and effectively?

My tools: Anything, if I need something I'll just buy it.

My time limiations: none.

My personal information: 23 years old, Male, Europoid, haven't trained in the last 5 months, 75 kilograms of bodyweight for 180 centimetres of height, normal testosterone levels but fluctuating above the average might be because the average is low.

Past training experience: 2 years of breakdance.

Type of endurance: move heavy weights for more reps

Comment: Battle ropes seem like a decent suggestion - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ff13cSWd_oE

Comment: *Swimming/kayaking too.

Comment: what do you mean by muscle endurance? Be able to use heavier weights or do more repetitions with the same weight?

Comment: As @Liiuc says, what kind of endurance? My first thought was an arm cycle.

Comment: A good recommendation will need to be specific to the outcome, and for that, we need a specific outcome.